# List in Python have limit?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a code to factor the number 600851475143 (my teacher must be mad at us). It runs normally up to position 10007 and even gives the primes 71 and 6857, but gives the error below the code below this message after that.

```
numero = 600851475143 #number
primos = [2,...,104729] # here is a list of 10000 primes that stackoverflow wouldn't let me insert
# ^ primes
ponteiro = 0 # pointer
cont = primos[0]
primos_usados = [] #used primes
while True:
    print(f"{ponteiro} - {cont}    {numero}\n{primos_usados}") # to see the values ​​per loop
    if(numero%primos[cont] == 0):
        numero = numero/primos[cont]
        primos_usados.append(primos[cont])
        ponteiro = 0
        if(numero/primos[cont] == 1):
            break
    ponteiro += 1
    cont = primos[ponteiro]
```

error:

if(numero%primos[cont] == 0):
IndexError: list index out of range

---

I manually tried to access the value primos[9999] but got the same error. how do I do this without having to either this error occur or I have to put 10000 numbers in a list?

Comment: If `cont` is an element of `primos` then why are you using it as if it is an index? It looks like you should have just written `primos_usados.append(cont)`.

Comment: Lists have no upper bound except the amount of memory you have installed on your machine. If you overflowed memory, it wouldn't be an index error. `print(len(primos))` will tell you how big the list is. `print(cont)` just before you are going to use it will tell you the failing number. Since `cont` seems to be values in the list, it wouldn't be the index of the list.